# Getting NIC speed from Powershell on Win2008 R2 Server

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008, powershell, nic

I am trying to get the NIC speed via Powershell on some of my servers. For my lab server I know there is a 1GB NIC in there. However, when I do this via Powershell I get the below weird number:

```
 Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "Name LIKE '%Intel%' OR Name LIKE '%HP%' OR Name LIKE '%Broadcom%'" | select name, speed | ft -AutoSize

name                                                       speed
----                                                       -----
Intel(R) 82580 Gigabit Network Connection    9223372036854775807
```

The speed I am getting back is "`9223372036854775807`" - I checked the WMI property for Speed in `Win32_NetworkAdapter` and it returns "`Bits per second`" - however, in conversion this looks like a lot more than 1GB per second?

Any idea on why I am getting this back and also the best way of determining NIC speed (and to confirm that it definitely is 1GB)?

As I have many servers - I really would prefer to know the best way of getting this info if you have any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Get a list of Domain Computers (Run in AD):

Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
Get-ADComputer -Filter * | ForEach-Object {$_.Name}

Or from a file:

```
$computers = Get-Content -Path computers.txt
```

For multiple computers:

```
foreach ($comp in $computers) {

   echo $comp
   Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapter -ComputerName $comp  | Select Name,Manufacturer,Description ,AdapterType,Speed,MACAddress,NetConnectionID | Where-Object {$_.AdapterType -like "*Ethernet*"}

}
```

That will print for each computer in list:

```
Name            : Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet
Manufacturer    : Broadcom Corporation
Description     : Broadcom NetLink (TM) Gigabit Ethernet
AdapterType     : Ethernet 802.3
Speed           : 1000000000
MACAddress      : B8:AC:6F:41:B5:D3
NetConnectionID : Ethernet
```

Note: Speed is in bits per second, convert to Gbps or Mbps as necessary

Answer (score 0):

For the original query, if you replace `speed` with `@{n="Speed";e={$_.speed/1mb}}`, it return a calculated result, in Mega-**bits**.

If you do `@{n="Speed";e={$_.speed/1gb}}`, it will return result in Gbits respectfully.

Powershell does not aware what the original measure is, and MB/mb is the same to powershell. Thus if you need the result to be in **bytes**, you have manually divide by the result by another 8,  `@{n="Speed";e={$_.speed/1mb/8}}`

The altered script would be:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapter -filter "Name LIKE '%Intel%' OR Name LIKE '%HP%' OR Name LIKE '%Broadcom%'" | select name, @{n="Speed";e={$_.speed/1gb}} | ft -AutoSize
```

And this alternative format `@{n="name";e={$_.property *operations*}}` would work for any select in powershell.